# Android Studio Error: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

Tags: android, android-studio, png, libpng

I was just wondering when Android studio shown an error: 
"libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited".

Can we get libpng and manually check if given PNG satisfies libpng.

Comment: You could get "pngcheck" and use that to inspect your PNG files.  It doesn't use libpng, but will tell you what's wrong with the image.

Comment: It didn't work in case of my libpng error:

Comment: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited. Any solution for this warning.

Comment: It's just a warning.  You can ignore it.  If it disturbs you, you can use a png editor such as pngcrush or ImageMagick to remove the iCCP chunk.

Comment: Actually this error won't let you upload app on google play.

Comment: Also, i can edit one, two, three icons, but for creating a lot of apps quickly, it's a great problem.

Comment: In the directory containing your PNGs, type "mogrify *.png".  This should quietly remove just the bad iCCP chunk from any PNG that has one (presuming you have an ImageMagick that was built with libpng16).  Or just throw away all of the iCCP chunks with "mogrify -strip *.png" (this will also remove any textual metadata too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **pngcrush** command line tool as follows to remomve iCCP chunks within PNGs

```
pngcrush.exe -rem iccp input.png output.png
```